# Use group price in shopping cart price rule conditions

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, group-price

Is there a properly way to use the product "group price" in the "shopping cart price rules" conditions, like the special_price attribute?

For some of my "shopping cart rules", I need to exclude from products that have special_price AND products that have group_price defined.

For the special_price, it is working out of the box.

Someone has probably already had the same requirement?

Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

NO there is no way.
Group price is not a simple attribute. It's value is saved as a serialized array that cannot be used in promo rules.